# Looking for a certain math symbol

Tags: math-mode, symbols

I have a very simple question.  I'm wondering how to type a certain symbol in TeX.  I've never encountered this symbol before today, and even after perusing the list of TeX symbols I can't find it.  I saw a problem like this:

Add

```
$6<200^\circ-4<50^\circ$
```

Except instead of `<200` the `200` was sort of... in the `<`.  Like the `<` was to the left and below the `200`.  Imagine `$\sqrt{200}$` but instead of a square root to the left and above, you have a `<` but to the left and below.

By the way, I tried Detexify.

Comment: [How to look up a symbol or identify a math symbol or character?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14)

Comment: I just tried to imagine what you are describing, but my imagination powers are limited. Can post a picture of the sign?

Comment: Package [steinmetz](http://ctan.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/steinmetz/steinmetz.pdf)?

Comment: Yes!  It's the \phase in steinmetz.  But hmm, looking at the original problem... that doesn't make much sense.  6 times 200 degrees minus 4 times 50 degrees?  Anyway, that's the symbol, thanks.  EDIT: the hand-written one was a liiiiitle more slanted, but I think that's just due to the writing.

Comment: @danzibr it means 6[cos(200°)+i sin(200°)]-4[cos(50°)+i sin(50°)]=-8.21-5.12i

Comment: @danzibr It's not 6*200 degrees - 4 * 50 degrees. It's subtracting one vector from another. The first has length 6 and leaves the origin at a 200 degree angle.

Comment: A quick search for `phase` in the [Comprehensive LaTeX symbols list](http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf) finds it as part of the [`steinmetz` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/steinmetz). So, this is a clear duplicate - the answer would have been found by scrolling through the documentation.

Comment: I voted for reopen: it may be useful reference for future visits. Maybe the OP could edit the title to make it more informative.

Comment: @Werner, I don't think this question is a duplicate: it hasn't been asked before and hasn't an answer yet. Yes, it's true that one of the answers to the other question leads to the answer for this one, but this question is not about searching for any symbol. Otherwise, every question that has an answer in the documentation of any package should be marked as duplicate.

Comment: @Luigi: That's true, and that's why we have [How to look up a symbol or identify a math symbol or character?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14/5764) as an FAQ. People should not just use Detexify and give up. They should look at other options and once that's been fully explored, ask a question here. Otherwise I would consider it a duplicate.

Comment: @ClaudioFiandrino: Closing a question doesn't mean it will be lost or deleted. Any voting behaviour on the question will cause it to remain visible to the community and any future visitors, including in the search results.

Comment: @Werner: True, but if a visitor comes and see it has been closed, she might have the feeling that the proposed solution is not perfect and immediately redirects to the duplicate.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You are describing the so called *Steinmetz notation* for complex numbers (or *angle notation*): the number on the left is the magnitude, the one on the right is the argument of the complex number.
You can use the `\phase` command from the [steinmetz](http://ctan.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/steinmetz/steinmetz.pdf) package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{steinmetz}

\begin{document}
$6\phase{200^\circ}-4\phase{50^\circ}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I'm asking who's the author of this famous package. `;-)`

Comment: @egreg, ça va sans dire

Answer (score 1):

This is just an extension of Luigi's [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/215212/15874) where the [`siunitx`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/siunitx) package is used to typeset the physical quantities in a consistent way:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{steinmetz}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

$6\phase{\ang{200}} - 4\phase{\ang{50}}$

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: I upvoted your answer. Even better to use the  `\ang` command from the siunitx package.